# Как скачать все картинки из figma в один клик?

Tags: вёрстка, figma

Была такая функция в photoshop. В фигме приходится по одному скачивать картинки из макета для верстки. Как скачать все картинки из figma в один клик?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нажать на кнопку, выбрать формат. И далее выбрать папку в которую сохраняться все изображения.

[image: Figma - меню справа]